# Find radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(2z)^n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

*Sorry for my last duplicate question. But for this question here, I did not find the same question*

Find radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(2z)^n}{n}$

$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$ with $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n(2z)^n}{n}$ with the radius of convergence $R = 1/L$

$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2z)^{n+1}n}{(-1)^{n}(2z)^{n}(n+1)}| = |\frac{(-1)(2z)n}{(n+1)}| = |\frac{(2z)}{(1+1/n)}| = |2z| < 1$ for $n \to \infty$. So we have $|z| < 1/2$

So we have $R = 1/L = 2$

Is that correct ?

Comment: Conclusion part is wrong. $R=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @geetha290krm What ? Why ? Isn't $R = 1/L$ ?

Comment: Is $z$ complex?

Comment: @wengen $R=\frac{1}{L}$, so...

Comment: @SineoftheTime I don't know, it is not indicated what $z$ is. It says that  we have to find the radius of convergence of this power serie, so I assume it is not complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{2}$ of the length of the interval of convergence, so $R=\frac{1}{2} length \left([-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ or alternatively $R=\frac{1}{L}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Ah I get it now. We have $|z| < 1/2$ so that means $z = [-1/2, 1/2]$ So the length of the interval of $z$ is $1$. I misunderstood $|z| < 1/2$ to imply that $L  = 1/2$ which would imply $R = 1/L = 2$

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence is $1/2$. You have showed this. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2z)^{n+1}n}{(-1)^{n}(2z)^{n}(n+1)} \right| = |2z| < 1$, then the series converges in $z$. If the limit is $>1$, it does not converge. So the largest disc such that the series suredly converges is all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|2z| < 1$ or $|z| < 1/2$. This is exactly what radius of convergence means.

I believe you have confused the limit you wrote down with something else, namely, if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (z-z_0)^n$ is a power series (in our case, $z_0 = 0$ and $c_n = (-1)^n\cdot 2^n / n$) then the radius of convergence is $R = 1/L$, where $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ if this limit exists. It does exist in our case. Note that this $L$ is different than the $L$ you defined. Hope this cleared some things.

In this case, we indeed have $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2)^{n+1}n}{(-1)^{n}(2)^{n}(n+1)} \right| = 2$ so $R = 1/2$.